# OpenCensusAgent trace provider (W3C Trace Standard) is not working in Istio

Tags: kubernetes, istio

My application code follows W3C Trace Context Standard for distributed tracing. But by default, Istio follows a different standard. I need to make istio to follow W3C Trace Standard. After some research I found istio supports OpenCensus trace provider which follows  W3C Trace Standard. When I add

How to use OpenCensusAgent in istio? to follow W3C Trace Context Standard

I have installed the below configuration (on top of *demo* profile) but still doesn't recognize `traceparent` header that is passed in the request.

```yaml
# openCensus.yaml
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  values:
    global: 
      proxy: 
        tracer: openCensusAgent
```

Install using below command

```sh
istioctl install -f openCensus.yaml
```

When I check in jagger, it shows it's still using zipkin

[image]

Here is the whole configuration of istio

```yaml
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  annotations:
    install.istio.io/ignoreReconcile: "true"
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"install.istio.io/v1alpha1","kind":"IstioOperator","metadata":{"annotations":{"install.istio.io/ignoreReconcile":"true"},"creationTimestamp":null,"name":"installed-state","namespace":"istio-system"},"spec":{"components":{"base":{"enabled":true},"cni":{"enabled":false},"egressGateways":[{"enabled":false,"name":"istio-egressgateway"}],"ingressGateways":[{"enabled":true,"name":"istio-ingressgateway"}],"istiodRemote":{"enabled":false},"pilot":{"enabled":true}},"hub":"docker.io/istio","meshConfig":{"defaultConfig":{"proxyMetadata":{}},"enablePrometheusMerge":true},"tag":"1.10.1","values":{"base":{"enableCRDTemplates":false,"validationURL":""},"gateways":{"istio-egressgateway":{"autoscaleEnabled":true,"env":{},"name":"istio-egressgateway","secretVolumes":[{"mountPath":"/etc/istio/egressgateway-certs","name":"egressgateway-certs","secretName":"istio-egressgateway-certs"},{"mountPath":"/etc/istio/egressgateway-ca-certs","name":"egressgateway-ca-certs","secretName":"istio-egressgateway-ca-certs"}],"type":"ClusterIP","zvpn":{}},"istio-ingressgateway":{"autoscaleEnabled":true,"env":{},"name":"istio-ingressgateway","secretVolumes":[{"mountPath":"/etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs","name":"ingressgateway-certs","secretName":"istio-ingressgateway-certs"},{"mountPath":"/etc/istio/ingressgateway-ca-certs","name":"ingressgateway-ca-certs","secretName":"istio-ingressgateway-ca-certs"}],"type":"LoadBalancer","zvpn":{}}},"global":{"configValidation":true,"defaultNodeSelector":{},"defaultPodDisruptionBudget":{"enabled":true},"defaultResources":{"requests":{"cpu":"10m"}},"imagePullPolicy":"","imagePullSecrets":[],"istioNamespace":"istio-system","istiod":{"enableAnalysis":false},"jwtPolicy":"third-party-jwt","logAsJson":false,"logging":{"level":"default:info"},"meshNetworks":{},"mountMtlsCerts":false,"multiCluster":{"clusterName":"","enabled":false},"network":"","omitSidecarInjectorConfigMap":false,"oneNamespace":false,"operatorManageWebhooks":false,"pilotCertProvider":"istiod","priorityClassName":"","proxy":{"autoInject":"enabled","clusterDomain":"cluster.local","componentLogLevel":"misc:error","enableCoreDump":false,"excludeIPRanges":"","excludeInboundPorts":"","excludeOutboundPorts":"","image":"proxyv2","includeIPRanges":"*","logLevel":"warning","privileged":false,"readinessFailureThreshold":30,"readinessInitialDelaySeconds":1,"readinessPeriodSeconds":2,"resources":{"limits":{"cpu":"2000m","memory":"1024Mi"},"requests":{"cpu":"100m","memory":"128Mi"}},"statusPort":15020,"tracer":"openCensusAgent"},"proxy_init":{"image":"proxyv2","resources":{"limits":{"cpu":"2000m","memory":"1024Mi"},"requests":{"cpu":"10m","memory":"10Mi"}}},"sds":{"token":{"aud":"istio-ca"}},"sts":{"servicePort":0},"tracer":{"datadog":{},"lightstep":{},"stackdriver":{},"zipkin":{}},"useMCP":false},"istiodRemote":{"injectionURL":""},"pilot":{"autoscaleEnabled":true,"autoscaleMax":5,"autoscaleMin":1,"configMap":true,"cpu":{"targetAverageUtilization":80},"deploymentLabels":null,"enableProtocolSniffingForInbound":true,"enableProtocolSniffingForOutbound":true,"env":{"ENABLE_LEGACY_FSGROUP_INJECTION":false},"image":"pilot","keepaliveMaxServerConnectionAge":"30m","nodeSelector":{},"replicaCount":1,"traceSampling":1},"telemetry":{"enabled":true,"v2":{"enabled":true,"metadataExchange":{"wasmEnabled":false},"prometheus":{"enabled":true,"wasmEnabled":false},"stackdriver":{"configOverride":{},"enabled":false,"logging":false,"monitoring":false,"topology":false}}}}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2021-06-15T14:27:44Z"
  generation: 2
  name: installed-state
  namespace: istio-system
  resourceVersion: "137011"
  uid: 6e6efc43-515a-4fdb-9681-329678d98a7d
spec:
  components:
    base:
      enabled: true
    cni:
      enabled: false
    egressGateways:
    - enabled: false
      name: istio-egressgateway
    ingressGateways:
    - enabled: true
      name: istio-ingressgateway
    istiodRemote:
      enabled: false
    pilot:
      enabled: true
      k8s:
        env:
        - name: PILOT_TRACE_SAMPLING
          value: "100"
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 100Mi
  hub: docker.io/istio
  meshConfig:
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
    defaultConfig:
      proxyMetadata: {}
    enablePrometheusMerge: true
  profile: demo
  tag: 1.10.1
  values:
    base:
      enableCRDTemplates: false
      validationURL: ""
    gateways:
      istio-egressgateway:
        autoscaleEnabled: true
        env: {}
        name: istio-egressgateway
        secretVolumes:
        - mountPath: /etc/istio/egressgateway-certs
          name: egressgateway-certs
          secretName: istio-egressgateway-certs
        - mountPath: /etc/istio/egressgateway-ca-certs
          name: egressgateway-ca-certs
          secretName: istio-egressgateway-ca-certs
        type: ClusterIP
        zvpn: {}
      istio-ingressgateway:
        autoscaleEnabled: true
        env: {}
        name: istio-ingressgateway
        secretVolumes:
        - mountPath: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs
          name: ingressgateway-certs
          secretName: istio-ingressgateway-certs
        - mountPath: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-ca-certs
          name: ingressgateway-ca-certs
          secretName: istio-ingressgateway-ca-certs
        type: LoadBalancer
        zvpn: {}
    global:
      configValidation: true
      defaultNodeSelector: {}
      defaultPodDisruptionBudget:
        enabled: true
      defaultResources:
        requests:
          cpu: 10m
      imagePullPolicy: ""
      imagePullSecrets: []
      istioNamespace: istio-system
      istiod:
        enableAnalysis: false
      jwtPolicy: third-party-jwt
      logAsJson: false
      logging:
        level: default:info
      meshNetworks: {}
      mountMtlsCerts: false
      multiCluster:
        clusterName: ""
        enabled: false
      network: ""
      omitSidecarInjectorConfigMap: false
      oneNamespace: false
      operatorManageWebhooks: false
      pilotCertProvider: istiod
      priorityClassName: ""
      proxy:
        autoInject: enabled
        clusterDomain: cluster.local
        componentLogLevel: misc:error
        enableCoreDump: false
        excludeIPRanges: ""
        excludeInboundPorts: ""
        excludeOutboundPorts: ""
        image: proxyv2
        includeIPRanges: '*'
        logLevel: warning
        privileged: false
        readinessFailureThreshold: 30
        readinessInitialDelaySeconds: 1
        readinessPeriodSeconds: 2
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 2000m
            memory: 1024Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
        statusPort: 15020
        tracer: openCensusAgent
      proxy_init:
        image: proxyv2
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 2000m
            memory: 1024Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 10Mi
      sds:
        token:
          aud: istio-ca
      sts:
        servicePort: 0
      tracer:
        datadog: {}
        lightstep: {}
        stackdriver: {}
        zipkin: {}
      useMCP: false
    istiodRemote:
      injectionURL: ""
    pilot:
      autoscaleEnabled: true
      autoscaleMax: 5
      autoscaleMin: 1
      configMap: true
      cpu:
        targetAverageUtilization: 80
      enableProtocolSniffingForInbound: true
      enableProtocolSniffingForOutbound: true
      env:
        ENABLE_LEGACY_FSGROUP_INJECTION: false
      image: pilot
      keepaliveMaxServerConnectionAge: 30m
      nodeSelector: {}
      replicaCount: 1
      traceSampling: 1
    telemetry:
      enabled: true
      v2:
        enabled: true
        metadataExchange:
          wasmEnabled: false
        prometheus:
          enabled: true
          wasmEnabled: false
        stackdriver:
          configOverride: {}
          enabled: false
          logging: false
          monitoring: false
          topology: false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to set some additional properties in order to work

```yaml
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  components:
    pilot:
      enabled: true
      k8s:
        env:
        - name: PILOT_TRACE_SAMPLING
          value: "100"
  values:
    global:
      proxy:
        tracer: openCensusAgent 
  meshConfig:
    enableTracing: true
    defaultConfig:
      tracing:
        openCensusAgent:
          address: "dns:opentelemetry-collector.istio-system.svc:55678"
          context: [W3C_TRACE_CONTEXT]
```